# How to attempt to read unallocated memory

Tags: c++, memory-management

Basically what I'm trying to ask is this:

```
char *buffer;
buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*bytes);
free(buffer);
//Somehow read buffer if possible,if it failed give return value ,but not crash or stop the whole program
//(examples as Segmentation fault and so on)
```

Is it possible to do just that?

Comment: May I ask *why* you want to do this?

Comment: @Borgleader Because I am making a level loader. And using buffers as levels.

Comment: But why *specifically* do you want to read un-allocated buffers?

Comment: That don't look like no c++ to me.

Comment: @Ben A glitch can happen like in all games.And because its easier to debug. :D

Comment: @Ben A glitch can happen like in all games.And because its easier to debug. :D ,sry didn't watch who was asking lol

Comment: If you're trying to detect unallocated memory, just have your allocator stamp freed memory with a special pattern, if you fetch that pattern, you'll know the buffer was deleted.

Comment: @Borgleader So you mean to make bool that checks whenever is the buffer active or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly can! Its just a **TERRIBLE** idea ....

You can deallocate `buffer`, but be prepared for *undefined behaviour* which include seg faults and other crazy things that you don't want. I have some suggestions:

1. If this is really c++, you shouldn't be using `malloc` you should be using `new` and `delete` or better yet `std::string` and `std::vector`.
2. You may be coming at this problem the wrong way, you should not be trying to read your already freed memory, but instead preserving memory that you think is necessary to read.
3. In regards to debugging, use a debugger, like `gdb` ...